# htaccess rewrite having trouble

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a few different type of URL's that might be experienced:
Examples:

- https://example.com/search/Bowling-Green/?doSearch=1&city=Bowling%20Green%20&%20Surrounding%20County
- https://example.com/search/?doSearch=1&neigborhood=North
  Ridge
- https://example.com/search/?doSearch=1&county=Logan County
- https://example.com/search/?doSearch=1&school=Barren County
  Middle
- https://example.com/search/?doSearch=1&zipcode=42104

So zipcode,school,county,city, neighborhood.

What I am trying to achieve is when one of these URL's is requested, it automatically changes the URL to

- https://example.com/search/city/BowlingGreen%20&%20Surrounding%20County/
- https://example.com/search/zipcode/42101/
- https://example.com/search/school/Barren County Middle/

.htaccess has been a pain for me, I have tried

```
RewriteRule    ^/search/neighborhood/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /search/?doSearch=1&neigborhood=$1    [NC,L]
```

But I am really not good at this and was seeing if I could get the assistance of someone on here to help write the correct (and stable rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} doSearch=1&(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule "^(search(.+))$"     /$1%1/%2/?  [L]
```

Update :

try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search/(.*)/(.*)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     /search?doSearch=1&%1=%2  [L]
```

The code above means if you request `/search/zipcode/42101/` it will be as it and goes internally to original path `/search?doSearch=1&zipcode=42101` and so on.

Comment: I don't have anything else setup, just this.